# matplotlib equivalent to skimage.io.imread(fname, as_grey=True)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-image

As this is a really common practice... I was wondering is the a matplotlib equivalent to this function in scikit-image?

```
from skimage import io
im = io.imread(fname, as_grey=True)
```

To read the RGB file to greyscale directly?

I need to use the matplotlib equivalent because I am using it to plot the result. And as I have observed, it seems the ndarray read by io.imread is not equivalent to that was read by plt.imread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can read in the image with `matplotlib.pyplot.imread`.  That will give you an RGB or RGBA image.  If you get an RGBA image, you'd probably want to discard the alpha layer:

```
rgb = rgba[..., :3]
```

You can obtain an approximation of the gray image by doing

```
rgb.mean(axis=2)
```

but that isn't exactly right.  One should multiply the channels with different weights and then combine them, i.e.

```
([0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721] * rgb).sum(axis=2)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the scikit-image plugin does not do anything strange to the values returned by matplotlib.  You can see the source here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/io/_plugins/matplotlib_plugin.py

Perhaps try: ``skimage.io.imread(fn, plugin='matplotlib')``

Answer (score 1):

If you have PIL, then you could read the file into a greyscale PIL image, and then convert that to a NumPy array:

```
import Image

img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('L')
arr = np.array(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `scipy.misc.imread` with `flatten=True`.  It depends on PIL being installed but returns an array object.

```
Docstring:
Read an image file from a filename.

Parameters
----------
name : str
    The file name to be read.
flatten : bool, optional
    If True, flattens the color layers into a single gray-scale layer.

Returns
-------
imread : ndarray
    The array obtained by reading image from file `name`.

Notes
-----
The image is flattened by calling convert('F') on
the resulting image object.
```